# How to access a JSON array element by its key name

Tags: json, mysql-5.7

Someone at my organization created a MySQL column with values that look like this:

```
[
 {"name1":"value1"},
 {"name2":"value2"},
 {"name3":[
   {"subname3.1":["subvalue3.1.1","subvalue3.1.2"]},
   {"subname3.2":["subvalue3.2.1","subvalue3.2.2"]},
   {"subname3.3":["subvalue3.3.1","subvalue3.3.2"]}
  ]},
 {"name4":"value4"}
]
```

The actual names vary from row to row, as do the number of array elements, but *no name is repeated* within a single row, and *no subname is repeated* within a single name within a single row.

I need the list of values `["subvalue3.1.1","subvalue3.2.1","subvalue3.3.1"]` in that order. But note that `name3` is not always third: its position varies: so I need to access it by name (`name3`).

I don't see anything at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html that will find it for me.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
col->>"$**.name3[*].*[0]"
```

This assumes that `name3` doesn't appear elsewhere as a name.